# How to deal with new versions of software when using Chef?

Tags: chef-infra

I have installed MySQL on a server using Chef. At the time I had installed the software, MySQL was version 5.6.36. Now version 5.6.40 of MySQL is available. If I set up a new server (or test locally with Kitchen) the new version is installed, but when I run the chef-client on the old server it says that there is nothing to do and it leaves the old version.

I think I could come up with a workaround (like creating a fake update of the recipe), but what is the best practice for this cases?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options depending on the workflow you want. The simplest option is to override the version in an attribute on each node as needed. This is the most direct way, but also the most high-touch since you have to manage things more or less manually for each relevant server. Another option is to use a wrapper cookbook which says which version you want to use (possibly with some logic about using different versions in different places), and then deliver that wrapper cookbook out through your normal workflow/pipeline when you want to make changes. You could also store the version in an environment or policy-group-level attribute. Which is best for you is entirely up to your current team and workflow.

Comment: I'd rather not touch the version because I would like to have it as maintenance-free as possible.

I have a more or less working solution. Specifically my recipe is using the mysql recipe from the supermarket; this recipe automatically installs mysql. I have added the following code:

`package 'mysql-community-server' do
   action :upgrade
end`

to enforce upgrading the server to the latest version and this seems to work. I'm just not sure if it's the best practice for this type of issues.

Comment: If you trust that MySQL will never release a buggy version, that’s fine. How much do you trust? :)

Comment: I actually have my own repo for MySQL, so I will manually add new versions of packages to my repo and then the recipe should pull the new versions and install them when available. Then I agree that this is a little bit like manually updating the version in the recipe.

Comment: Yep, then `action :upgrade` is definitely the way to go :)